# How to analyse the source code of Blender

Tags: blender, blender-2.50

I am a beginner of Blender, my professor asked me to read the source code of Blender 2.6 and study how blender implements the material and texture block. After i have downloaded the source code, i find it is impossible for me to read whole source code, especially without detailed comment and professional manual. Is there anybody can give me some advice or offer me some learning material? For example, i am confused by how multiple layers of texture are compounded by using different blend type, like mix, add, subtract or overlay. How does blender implement these functionality?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at the code layout diagram [here](http://www.blender.org/bf/codelayout.jpg).

Comment: I really appreciate your help. After i read the docs about outline of blender, i get shallow understanding. However, i want to know how blender implements material and texture block, so i search blender wiki and Google many times, but there is litter material about this. Could your recommend me some docs or books?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to get the source code and import the code into an IDE like QtCreator (import make file project). From there on, you can easily browse for the details.What you are looking for is a DNA entry.So look in the file DNA_MAterial_Types.h You can find the declarations for all the material types.